# returning an arraylist of arraylist from a resultset in java

Tags: java, sql, arraylist, prepared-statement, resultset

I created a database wrapper class in java and created a method called `fetchAll(query)`.

```
this.openConnection();

ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
PreparedStatement stmt = this.conn.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet resultset = stmt.executeQuery();

ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultset.getMetaData();
int numcols = metadata.getColumnCount();

while (resultset.next()) {
    int i = 1;
    while (i < numcols) {
        results.add(resultset.getString(i++));
    }
}

this.closeConnection();

return results;
```

Now it returns something like this:

```
[1, name1, address1, age1, 2, name2, address2, age2, 2, name2, address2, age3]
```

Which I found odd and the method does not return all columns, it lacks 1 column, why is it?

How can I achieve something like this

```
[
  [1,name1,address1,age1,bday1],
  [2,name2,address2,age2,bday2],
  [3,name3,address3,age3,bday3]
]
```

Comment: getting downvote without saying a thing. stupid fella.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();  // List of list, one per row
...
while (resultset.next()) {
    List<String> row = new ArrayList<>(numcols); // new list per row
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= numcols) {  // don't skip the last column, use <=
        row.add(resultset.getString(i++));
    }
    result.add(row); // add it to the result
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the inner loop is a `while` and not a `for each`?
For me I personally would prefer a `for loop` for the sake of readability, but maybe the `while` has a reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(sql);//from DB      
    int numcols = resultset.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    List <List <String> > result = new ArrayList<>();

    while (resultset.next()) {
        List <String> row = new ArrayList<>(numcols); // new list per row

        for (int i=1; i<= numcols; i++) {  // don't skip the last column, use <=
            row.add(resultset.getString(i));
            System.out.print(resultset.getString(i) + "\t");
        }
        result.add(row); // add it to the result
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```